# How to dynamically skip top rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I've been trying to figure out how I can dynamically skip the rows and create a new table from this table with the `departmentID` and `departmentName` instead of the `unnamed_1` and `unnamed_2`. I'm attempting to make the program automatically take whichever row has the `departmentName` and `departmentID` in it. I've included the picture for reference.

*Edit:* The main problem is that I'm trying to find a way to automatically have it to where it replaces `unnamed_1` and `_2` with these `departmentID` and Name without me having to modify the options aside from running the program.
[image]

Comment: what language? what program? you can alias the select clause in the sql statement.

Comment: As for the question, have a look at the `OFFSET` clause. However, the problem appears to be your data and import process; that's what you should be fixing. I smell an [XY Problem](http://XYproblem.info).

Comment: My bad @Larnu, I had a slight typo. I meant for it to say 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this, might be helpful:

```sql
SELECT departmentId, departmentName FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber, 
    C.RowNumber AS RowLimit, 
    B.Unamed_1 AS departmentId, 
    B.Unamed_2 AS departmentName 
FROM [WhatEverTableItIs] AS B
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNumber,
        Unamed_1, 
        Unamed_2 
    FROM [WhatEverTableItIs]) AS C 
ON C.Unamed_1 = 'departmentID' AND C.Unamed_2 = 'departmentName') A
WHERE RowNumber > RowLimit
```

It will join the table with itself on the row that has `departmentID` as `Unamed_1` and `departmentName` as `Unamed_2`. It calculates row number and use it as a key (just like a primary key) then filters rows with row number less than the speciefic row number which is we joined tables on.

Comment: I'll test it with my program as soon as I get back to my computer. Thank you for your well thought out response!

Comment: Beware! `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is effectively "order any which way and not necessarily in a consistent manner". With 2 uses of ROW_NUMBER that should be double the risk of inconsistency but perhaps the optimizer can eliminate one usage.